1970s heist movie
American comedy in colour from 1970s. Not as late as 1980.
I believe they wanted to steal some jewellery, gold or similar. Do not think it was money.
There was some car chasing, with some (red?) car I believe. IIRC the driver was rather enthusiastic. For some reason I remember a record (LP) with some car engines or similar, but not sure how it fits in. Some / all wore flared pans (thus I believe 1970s). For some reason they also had a fight with the police and believe there was some helicopter either chasing or flying the robbers. Believe they also used some bombs or smoke bombs in a sand-pit or ravine.
It was a contemporary film set in some (bigger) city. Do not remember if they were successful or not.

Update:
Thinking about it I now believe it was a diamond heist. Scribbling down words on a piece of paper I ended up with:
Heist, helicopter, US-City (New-York?), Bombs in sand-pit, diamond, fight with police, car chase, LP-motor, scarf, bananas, elevator, comedy, color, 1970s, flared-pants, sunglasses, suits, ties, summer, action.
Not sure how or if all the words fit in. Believe the city was New-York, or some similar to it, (Sky scrapers etc.).

Hrm, I know it's much later, but there are a LOT of elements similar to "The Italian Job".

@JohnP: Have seen "The Italian Job" (more recently) and it's not that one, but thanks for suggestion.

If you hadn't said American, there is the 1969 version of the Italian Job, but it's British.

@JohnP: Yes. Have seen that one. The reason I stand for it being American is what I vaguely recall from the police uniforms/cars + the city. It was more like New-York then a European city.

After some more scribbling and word guessing I suddenly got a vague picture of a young Robert Redford. As such it led me to The Hot Rock. Not sure how bananas fits into the story though :P (or if it does) – have to get a hold of that one and view it again.
Staring:

Robert Redford as John Dortmunder
George Segal as Andy Kelp
Ron Leibman as Stan Murch
Paul Sand as Allan Greenberg
Moses Gunn as Dr. Amusa
Zero Mostel as Abe Greenberg

From review section of IMDB:

This film is taken from one of a series of books by Donald E. Westlake about John Dortmunder & his various cronies who try to pull off big capers but never quite succeed.

From the looks of it I surely wish they would have made this into a franchise/film series.
Bananas fits in with comment from @Will Feldman and is also mentioned in Wikipedia plot section.
Thanks for hints and tips.
Trailer



@JohnP: Yes, thanks. I'm actually a bit exited about finding this movie. It looks kind of fun in that laid back, durable, kind of way. Do not know why I did not recall RR earlier, perhaps because I was only about six when I saw it ... It also say I have to wait 2 days before I can accept own answer.

Bananas fit into the story because a post-hypnotic trigger phrase used in the movie was "Afghanistan banana stand".

@WillFeldman: Ah, fun. That's rather beyond me as English is not my native tongue. Not sure how I managed to pick up "bananas". Bute believe we had it on VHS and as such I saw it at least a couple of times (in secret). Guess I saw it as 7 as well. After viewing some clips I surely also remember Murch more vividly.
